# iis url rewrite user-friendly urls multiple rules conflict

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-8, url-rewrite-module

I've been trying to create user-friendly urls for two of my cfm pages using url rewrite module on IIS 8. That said, there seems to be some sort of conflict due to similarity between rules or something.

Here is what I want to achieve. The following pages:

```
www.mywebsite.com/news.cfm?category=microsoft
www.mywebsite.com/news.cfm?category=apple
etc

www.mywebsite.com/blog.cfm?title=sometitle
www.mywebsite.com/blog.cfm?title=sometitle
etc
```

Should look like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/news/microsoft
or this
www.mywebsite.com/microsoft

www.mywebsite.com/blog/sometitle
or this
www.mywebsite.com/sometitle
```

You get the picture.

Here is my code:

```
<rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL4" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^news\.cfm$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^category=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="news/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL4" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^news/([^/]+)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="news.cfm?category={R:1}" />
</rule>

<rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL5" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^blog\.cfm$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^title=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="blog/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL5" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^blog/([^/]+)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="blog.cfm?title={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

The rules above do not work together and both pages redirect to the one that's set in the first rule. Can this be done with a single rule or do I need to use two? How can I sort this out? I would really appreciate your help on this one. I am using ColdFusion 10 on Windows and IIS 8.

Comment: I know is too late but how did you solve this issue? I have the same one